# Adding roles to existing ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have created a document upload site with ASP.NET Core Web Application, and I selected the authentication as Individual Accounts, but I want to be able to add roles to the users.

How I want it to work is, a superuser will create admin users, and admins will create normal users, and when creating a user I want to be able to select a role, but I don't think this is included in the basic Individual Accounts authentication.

Most articles/questions I've looked at reference using the startup class or controllers and my application doesn't have either of these. It just has Models and Razor pages - with Page models behind.

How can I add this in?

Comment: If you know how to do this with controllers, you should pretty much do the same thing with Razor Pages. What have you tried?

Comment: @YossiSternlicht I don't know how to do it with controllers, I've read some articles that use controllers but I wasn't sure how to amend it to work with razor pages.